# How can I expand and edit the result of a command substitution in Bash?

Tags: bash, debian, macos

Is it possible to expand and edit the result of a command substitution `$(<cmd>)` in Bash?

Suppose that `<cmd>` results in another command that I want to execute. Indeed, `$(<cmd>)` will execute that command, but it won't be visible in `history`, so I can't go back and edit it.

The only way I've solved this problem is to assign the output of `$(<cmd>)` to a variable, `cmd=$(<cmd>)`, and then echoing that into the clipboard using `pbcopy` on macOS: `echo $cmd | pbcopy`.

Comment: Are you using macOS or Debian? Which system should the solution work on? Also, can you give us a specific example so we can test it?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands `shell-expand-line`

Answer (score 4):

You can expand all shell substitions in the current command line.

> **[shell-expand-line (M-C-e)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands)** -
>    Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions ([see Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)).

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Example:

```
$ echo $(curl -s ifconfig.io)
# press ctrl+esc+e,
# command line will switch to:
$ echo 151.101.1.69
```

Note, that I added `-s` to `curl` to avoid `stderr` mingling with the command line. For other commands, you might want to use `2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 3):

I use Bash in Kubuntu on a non-Apple laptop. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> expands many things in the command line, including `$(whatever)`. I'm not sure how the keystroke "translates" to the Mac keyboard. The point is to trigger the [`shell-expand-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) command.

Notes:

- errors from `whatever` can interrupt your flow
- other things will be expanded inline as well
- quoting will be lost

Therefore I think it's good to type `$(whatever)` first, expand it, only then add the rest.